# How to integrate following integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

How to integrate following integral i am having physics background and i am trying calculating the induced charge in a specific problem.
The Integral need to be evaluted is 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+b^2)^{3/2}}\,dxdy$$

Comment: polar coordinates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $b\not=0$, then, by letting $x=r\cos(t)$ and $y=r\sin(t)$ ([polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system)) the integral becomes
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+b^2)^{3/2}}\,dxdy&=
\int_{r=0}^{\infty}\int_{t=0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{(r^2+b^2)^{3/2}}\,(rdrdt)\\
&=\left[-\frac{2\pi}{(r^2+b^2)^{1/2}}\right]_0^{\infty}=\frac{2\pi}{|b|}.
\end{align*}

P.S. The integral can be done also by using cartesian coordinates
\begin{align*}4\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x^2+y^2+b^2)^{3/2}}\right) dy
&=4\int_{0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{x}{(y^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2+b^2)^{1/2}}\right]_{x=0}^{\infty}dy\\
&=4\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dy}{y^2+b^2}
=\frac{4}{|b|}\left[\arctan\left(\frac{y}{|b|}\right)\right]_{y=0}^{\infty}\\&=\frac{2\pi}{|b|}
\end{align*}

Comment: yeah sure Robert thank you so much.

Comment: What substitution would you recommend for evaluating just $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(c^2+x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\,\mathrm{d}x$?

Comment: I see, thanks..

Comment: @StubbornAtom The primitive is $x/(y^2+c^2)/((x^2+y^2+c^2)^{1/2}$.

Comment: @Ashuotsh Pandey Cartesian coordinates work too (see PS)